# Google search console fails to fetch sitemaps | "Sitemap could not be read"

Tags: seo, search-engine, sitemap, google-search-console

I have generated a sitemap from online generators, it seems to be working and even i tested it on old google search console sitemap testor and it works. but when i submit it in both versions it just displays error message.

[image]

Comment: I have the same issue. Did u fix it? please share the solution.

Comment: I have the same issue too. My index_sitemap.xml are working except page-sitemap.xml GSC says that couldn't fetch?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [Google Search Console Adding Sitemap "Couldn't fetch" and "Sitemap could not be read" txt file](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/127718/google-search-console-adding-sitemap-couldnt-fetch-and-sitemap-could-not-be)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a known bug. See [this Google support answer](https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/3105916?hl=en).

Comment: I FOUND A FIX ... change the line feed to Unix (LF)... this setting is in BBedit at the bottom of the window. The online generator created a sitemap with line feed as "Windows (CRLF)". Changed it to Unix (LF) and success.  I am not able to post an answer here.

Comment: @RandyZeitman I doubt that's the ONLY factor causing this issue. I develop code on Linux & I ensure all of my committed files has LF line endings (using `git`), yet I', still facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it's the sitemap that had a syntax error.
You should open sitemaps in Firefox, it will tell you if you have a syntax error.

Comment: No it was correct i tested it with the old GSC and no issues... but still doesn't work

Comment: It's my experience. This don't help you but could help other people.

Answer (score 0):

Your sitemap domain address might have changed. If it is wordpress use yoast plugin, where search console will automatically consider sitemap.xml

Comment: Its not wordpress, but i visit the address that i give to google and it returns my sitemap which is correct? everything is okay i don't know why this happens

Comment: Please send website domain

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was because I didn't set the content-type to `application/xml`

This sitemap validator notified me of the issue: https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/validate-xml-sitemap.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the Yoast SEO plugin which built out 10 sitemaps, the index got red the first time and only one of the sub-sitemaps did. I manually visited the other sitemaps (likely they took to long to respond I thought) and deleted the sitemap on google search console and re-uploaded. All were read that time.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the full URL of your sitemap, e.g., https://example.com/sitemap.xml. Also, ensure your sitemap name does not include numbers and symbols.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and the solution was very simple, just put the full path to your sitemap.

Where the console asks 'add new sitemap', instead of writing `/sitemap.xml`, write the full path, such as `https://example.com/sitemap.xml`.

That should fix the problem.

Comment: This didn't make any difference in my case. The issue is still there